# Opening emacs inside the terminal using Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, linux, emacs, runtime.exec

I have a program that is emulating a simple distributed file system. I need to be able to open a file locally using emacs in the terminal window to read or write. I am using Runtime.exec() on an String[] to represent the commands. If I use "emacs" I can get the machine I'm currently using to open an emacs window (this doesn't help for any other machines running the Client). However, I have been unable to resolve how to have emacs open within the terminal using this process. I've tried adding the parameter "-nw" but it does not seem to respond. This is what I'm currently trying to use:

```
boolean bool = execute("emacs", "-nw", cachedFile);

private boolean execute(String com, String id, String fileName) {

            String[] commands = new String[3];
            commands[0] = com;
            commands[1] = id;
            commands[2] = fileName;


            try {                              
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
                int blah = p.waitFor();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
 }
```

If I drop the "-nw" then I can get only the machine that I'm working on locally to open a separate window for the GUI emacs. This is not helpful because I need other remote machines (that I'm connected thru with terminal) to be able to view or edit the file and X does not work since I'm not at those machines to see the new window.

I know for sure that "emacs -nw filename" is the proper command because if I manually type this into the terminal then it'll open emacs. However, I want the Runtime.exec() to manage this request.

Comment: While you can launch emacs in a Process, OutputStream - ErrorStream and InputStream are not a built-in Java "curses" implementation.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what do you mean by this?

Comment: Java provides built in line based output mechanisms, there is no *console* drawing primitives (like *curses* or *termcap*), like emacs and vim use to draw on the console.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So because the program itself is running the command then emacs doesn't have a way to draw to the screen (open)?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.